# How to read data from firestore and display it in mobile app

Tags: database, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, mobile

I'am using flutter in making my mobile app. I wanted to display specific data from my database in firebase into my app. The problem is that when I run hasData the output says it has no data but I already have some data inputted in my collection in firestore.

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('customers')
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (
                BuildContext context,
                AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot,
              ) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  var data = 'No Data';
                  return Text(data);
                }
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  var data = 'Loading';
                  return Text(data);
                }
                final data = snapshot.requireData;
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: data.size,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Container(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            detailsWidget(
                              icon: Icons.person,
                              field: 'Name',
                              value: '${data.docs[index]['name']}',
                            ),
                            detailsWidget(
                              icon: Icons.order,
                              field: 'Order',
                              value: '${data.docs[index]['order']}',
                            ),
           
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    });
              }),
```

I initialized the variable in a separate class

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
class DatabaseManagement {


 final CollectionReference customerList =
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('customers');
 Future<void> createUserData(
String name,
String order,
String uid,
  ) async {
return await customerList.doc(uid).set({
  'name': name,
  'order': order
});


 }

}
```

Now I don't know how to improve my code to make the output shows up

Answer (score 0):

Try This code.

```
    StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                      .collection('customers')
                      .snapshots(),
                  builder: (
                    BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot,
                  ) {


                    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                        case ConnectionState.none:
                        case ConnectionState.waiting:
                              var data = 'Loading';
                              return Text(data);
                        case ConnectionState.active:
                        case ConnectionState.done:
                        
                          if (snapshot.hasData) {
                             var data = 'No Data';
                               return Text(data);
                          } else {
                           final data = snapshot.requireData;
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: data.size,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return Container(
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                detailsWidget(
                                  icon: Icons.person,
                                  field: 'Name',
                                  value: '${data.docs[index]['name']}',
                                ),
                                detailsWidget(
                                  icon: Icons.oder,
                                  field: 'Order',
                                  value: '${data.docs[index]['order']}',
                                ),
               
                              ],
                            ),
                          );
                        });
                          }
              
                        default:
                          return const Center(
                            child: Text("Somethign went wrong"),
                          );
                      }
                  }),
```

Comment: it did'nt work now after I did that it returns no output.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: After I followed your code it still says no data. I think the the reason why hasData always returns a null output is because I haven't initialize my variables yet. I edited my question please help me